# c++ program shows how many symbols have changed

Tags: c++

How can i make programm to show how many symbols i changed?

```
std::cout << "Choose symbol to change to " << zva << " : ";
std::cin >> simbols;

std::cout << "\n\n";
std::replace_if(code.begin(), code.end(), [simbols](char ch) {return ch == simbols; }, zva);
std::cout << "text:" << code << '\n';
std::cout << "\n\n";

std::cout << " - symbols changed.\n";
```

Comment: Well, you could compare your before string to your after string.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've posted? What is the expected input and output? Please show a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

Just `count` how many characters you'll *need* to change before changing them.

```
auto result = std::count(code.begin(), code.end(), simbols);
```

Also, you don't need the `_if` version of `replace` since you don't need to do any transformation to the values to check if they need to be replaced.

```
std::replace(code.begin(), code.end(), simbols, zva);
```